# Write list elements to fields in a csv-file in python using the csv modul

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, csv

i got a textfile **BM.txt** the content looks like this:

```
*A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7AB A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7BE A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001  B7CD A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7D4*
```

**In my code:**
I want to seperate elements by 26 charackters. Each element of 26 chars is a element in the list:

```
import csv #import csv modul using writerows function 
#csv docs https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

#open the file with the string element to seperate bm elements.
    file = open("BM.txt", "r")
    c = file.read()
#list comp that seperates the elements by 26 charackters each
    neue_liste = [c[i:i+26] for i in range(0, len(c), 26)] 

#creating a new file with the bm elements as comma seperated values
    with open('briefmarken.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)
        writer.writerows(neue_liste)
    file.close()
```

The result of the list comprehension looks promising:

```
['A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7AB ', 'A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7BE ', 'A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7CD ',.....]
```

But when i finally write the list with the writerow()-function.
The content in the **csv** looks like this:

```
A,0, ,0,1,9,4, ,7,F,9,E, ,0,0, ,0,0,0,1, ,B,7,A,B, 
A,0, ,0,1,9,4, ,7,F,9,E, ,0,0, ,0,0,0,1, ,B,7,B,E, 
A,0, ,0,1,9,4, ,7,F,9,E, ,0,0, ,0,0,0,1, ,B,7,C,D, 
....
```

Really this is good enough for my work but i wonder why every charackter is now comma seperated? And iam looking at the posts and the csv docs but i dont get it.

Maybe someone can answert this question.

Thanks in advance

Ben

Comment: What do you want the row to look like?  Do you want it to be `A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7AB` or `A0,0194,7F9E,00,0001,B7AB` or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're writing a list of strings using `csv.writerows`, which writes *several* rows.

This function accepts an iterable of iterables. So when passing a list of strings, you're satisfying the input but it's not what you're expecting: the strings are seen as iterables, and are split character by character.

To write all your data, 1 string per row, use:

```
writer.writerows([x] for x in neue_liste)
```

(well, `csv` module is hardly useful in that case, better use `writelines` on a file handle)

To write all your data in 1 row use `writerow` (note the lack of `s` in the end):

```
writer.writerow(neue_liste)
```

although comments suggest wisely that you want to split your strings again according to spaces, then use:

```
writer.writerows(x.split() for x in neue_liste)
```

or

```
writer.writerows(map(str.split,neue_liste))
```

Comment: On the off chance that he wants rows looking like `A0,0194,7F9E,00,0001,B7AB` he could do `neue_liste = [c[i:i+26].split() for i in range(0, len(c), 26)]` and leave everything else the same.

Comment: To add. When you use `writerows`, then each element of the list is treated as iterable row. As it is a string, the iterator considers each letter of the string as the element of the row. This is the reason why you see each element separated. As @StevenRumbalski wrote, you may alternatively want to loop through each `element` of the `neue_liste`, get the `row = element.split()`, and use the `writer.writerow(row)`.

Comment: good points. Edited with third alternative, probably what op wants.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I want the elements to split each in a row. like                            A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7AB 
A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7BE 
A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7CD 
A0 0194 7F9E 00 0001 B7D4                                                                                     This totally worked for me thx